# Django query which work faster "between" or __gte, __lte

Tags: django, django-queryset

I need to find data for one month so which query work faster "between" OR "__gte" and "__lte" ?

Answer (score 3):

Sample code using `timeit` module

```
from timeit import timeit

setup = 'from app.models import Model'
timeit('Model.objects.filter(field__gte="2018-02-20 12:22:00")', setup=setup)
timeit('Model.objects.filter(field__lte="2018-02-20 12:22:00")', setup=setup)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the range for getting data between two dates

```
data = Model.objects.filter(date__range(date1,date2))
```

Refer documentation

[Documentation for db queries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/queries/)

Answer (score -1):

- `range` operator:
- Clarity: More concise and readable, especially for simple month-based
  filtering.
- Performance: This can be faster depending on the database engine and
  specific query. Some databases optimize range queries efficiently.

2.`__gte` and `__lte` operators:

- Clarity: This can be verbose, especially for complex filtering
  involving multiple fields.
- Performance: Might be slightly slower than
  `range` in some cases, but usually negligible.